# How can we achieve before_save kind of callbacks in ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I would like to understand how Ar callbacks are implemented in ActiveRecord? I kind of guessing this can be achieved with Ruby hook methods but, I am not sure how I can implement this in ruby. Any pointers or links for this would be much appreciated.

Comment: I don't know exactly how the hooks are implemented in ActiveRecord but the easiest way to do this is to use proxied objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [AR source foir callbacks](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb). Basically, it uses [ActiveModel callbacks](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activemodel/lib/active_model/callbacks.rb) which uses [ActiveSupport callbacks](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb).

There is a lot of metaprogramming involved, but what it basically does is calling all `before_` callbacks before running the proper method (that's what `super` is for). If you want to be able to code callbacks as easily as ActiveRecord, use ActiveSupport as it does. Otherwise, you can go with something like:

```
def method_with_callback
  if !respond_to?(:before_callback) || before_callback
    //method
    after_callback if respond_to? :after_callback
  end
end
```

But ActiveSupport approach is more modular and easier to maintain.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to see `ActiveSupport::Callbacks`, you need no more than this to have callbacks for any method.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Callbacks.html

Comment: what's the added value of your answer over @Serabe's?

Comment: perhaps this link added some value.. While there were no answer, I wrote a lot, and then I made things more simple to @Vamsi. But Serabe posted first. Should I delete this? I don't think so.